Can't load `libboost_ext_fwk` on Flutter Android
I was trying to run File Manager App
Skipped 1165 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
Can't load libboost_ext_fwk
GraphicExtModuleLoader::CreateGraphicExtInstance false

While running the app I get this error
